# git-svn dcommit from post-commit with Kerberos

Tags: git, git-svn, kerberos

I'd like to have git automatically push local changes to the upstream subversion repo when a commit is made. The SVN repo authenticates using Kerberos, so there's no need to hardcode a password or anything into the commit hook.

The obvious way to do this is to put "git svn dcommit" into the post-commit hoook, but unfortunately, git appears to be stripping environment variables (like `KRB5CCNAME`, which Kerberos needs) before calling the hooks.

So the question is: how do I change the environment variables that are passed to the commit hook?

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't doing this negate one of the benefits of using Git?  Namely, developing locally on a sort of topic branch, isolated from changes made by other devs, and pushing an entire feature to svn at once?

Comment: Yes, if we were using git as a dev tool. We're not, cobbler is using git internally to store a revision history of it's runtime configuration. So I want it to push this upstream immediately when a sysadmin runs the CLI tool to make a change.

Comment: i have to admit i don't know anything about kerberos, but are you forced to rely on environment variables ? can't you just use a hook script that access variables stored in some text file ?

Comment: Kerberos stores a credentials cache in a file on disk, which is named randomly, but who's name is exported via the environment variable given. I've looked at the other scripts to see if there was a way to pass the cache location along via other means (i.e. create a symlink to a consistently-named file in pre, delete in post), but it looks like the environment is stripped for all the relevant hooks.

Comment: Git does not strip the enviroment for me.  I used `echo $KRB5CCNAME` as post-commit hook, and it successfully showed the value of the environment variable.  (git version 1.7.2.3 on Linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was the environment variable getting stripped by sudo on the box---I added it to list of environment variables to be preserved in /etc/sudoers.

Turns out it was a bug in earlier RHEL5 installations which has since been fixed.